# Laravel Collection installation with Composer and Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravelcollective

I need help with a problem.

I'm learning Laravel 5.
And I've found a problem trying to do something.

I tried to install Laravel Collection.
I go to *composer.json* and I add this line on *require:*

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
```

But when I execute *composer update* on shell, I have an error:
**Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.**
And a lot of posibles conclusions to the problem.

I put a screenshot to help you to understand.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the error messages are clear. You are trying to install a package that has a dependency of laravel componenents with a version of 5.1, but in your composer.json file, you imply that your project works with laravel 5.0. Either change the `laravelcollective/html`  version to 5.0.* or change and upgrade your laravel dependency as 5.1.* so that your problem will be solved.